# Add uncheck all checkbox for TreeView

Tags: c#, web-applications

I have a `TreeView` with a checkbox in for each node.  I also have one checkbox outside of the tree which, when clicked needs to uncheck all of the checkboxes inside of the tree.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion to iterate the hole treeview and set the checked-property to true

```
private void Node(TreeNode root)
{
   root.Checked = true;

   foreach (TreeNode childNode in root.Nodes)
   {     
      childNode.Checked = true;

      Node(childNode);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i hav one check box when i uncheck the checkbox that placed outside the panel out the treeview on that time the checkbox value of treeview should be uncheck

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you but if what you want to do is to alternate between checked and unchecked state just pass the boolean as a parametre and set it to false when you need the checkboxes to be unchecked and visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if checkbox is unchecked
    if (!CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        //uncheck all checkboxes of tree view
        foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Add an event handler on the checkbox outside the panel

```
<asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```